# Change class of img with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the class of an image with jquery which worked perfectly fine until I updated Safari to 16.1. The class is actually changing but it doesn’t show the new styles on the image.

Is there anything I am doing wrong or am I missing something?

```js
$( "#change-it" ).on( "click", function () {
    $( "#change-me" ).removeClass( "image-fx-moon" ).addClass( "image-fx-rise" );
});
```

```css
.image-fx-moon {
  filter: grayscale(0.99) contrast(1.1) brightness(1.1);
}

.image-fx-rise {
  filter: saturate(0.75) contrast(0.85) brightness(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="change-me" class="image-fx-moon" src="https://www.isorauschen.at/gallery/articles/main/amazingplacesv_311224_1.jpg" width=400 height=auto />


<button id="change-it" type="button">
  Change
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0789ecdt/

Comment: Did you accidently remove the period in the CSS Selector for **image-fx-rise ** when you posted it here? I see you have it in your jsfiddle

Comment: Ah yes sorry copy/paste mistake.

Comment: Definitely seems to be a Safari bug. Sometimes the colours change, sometimes they don't. The class _is_ changing though